# Other hosts cannot connect to websocket server on my host

Tags: websocket

First of all, sorry for my bad English : )

My Java application (multiplayer game server) uses this package to communicate with a web application in client's browser using websockets: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

I've encountered a problem running my application: only I can connect to the websocket server, clients on other hosts can't do so. In browser I estabilish connection as usual, address here is certainly correct:

```
new WebSocket("ws://"+serverIp+":8787");
```

When I connect from my own host to the websocket server running on the same host, it runs perfectly. When other hosts try to connect to me, connection in not being estabilished: in browser WebSocket objects's .readyState is 0 (whilst it should be 1), and even server does not recieve any handshakes (no output from onClientOpen in server console, I even tried to get any output from certain WebSocketServer class' methods).

Other hosts are still recieving, for example, static contents of web application from webserver on 80 port on the same host. Problem is not the closed 8787 port: I checked it, it's open.

What may be the reason that other host can't connect to my websocket server?

Comment: What does the IP look like? Is it a private IP or public IP?

Answer (score 3):

WebSockets uses a cross-origin permission system. You might need to tell you WebSocket server to accept connections from more than just your local host. The verification of Origin happens during the WebSocket handshake which likely happens prior to onclientOpen.